# EXPECTED BEGIN_ARRAY BUT WAS BEGIN_OBJECT AT LINE 1 COLUMN 2 PATH $22

Tags: arrays, json, android-studio, retrofit

I want to access JSON array . so I created 2 Object !!Have a look at my code , Url

Url-***cricapi.com/api/matches/?apikey=JimJAfsmRGOnDpCrRrqO6htlilg1***
My MatchesArrayClass

```
package com.piyushjaiswal.jsonpractis;

public class MatchesArray {
    private Matches matches;

   private provider provider2;

    public MatchesArray(Matches matches, provider provider2) {
        this.matches = matches;
        this.provider2 = provider2;
    }

    public Matches getMatches() {
        return matches;
    }

    public void setMatches(Matches matches) {
        this.matches = matches;
    }

    public provider getProvider2() {
        return provider2;
    }

    public void setProvider2(provider provider2) {
        this.provider2 = provider2;
    }
}
```

**Matches Class**

```
package com.piyushjaiswal.jsonpractis;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Matches {
    private int unique_id;
    private String date;
    private String dateTimeGMT;
    @SerializedName("team-1")
    private String team1;
    @SerializedName("team-2")
    private String team2;
    private String type;
    private String toss_winner_team;
    private boolean squad;
    private boolean matchStarted;

    public int getUnique_id() {
        return unique_id;
    }

    public void setUnique_id(int unique_id) {
        this.unique_id = unique_id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDateTimeGMT() {
        return dateTimeGMT;
    }

    public void setDateTimeGMT(String dateTimeGMT) {
        this.dateTimeGMT = dateTimeGMT;
    }

    public String getTeam1() {
        return team1;
    }

    public void setTeam1(String team1) {
        this.team1 = team1;
    }

    public String getTeam2() {
        return team2;
    }

    public void setTeam2(String team2) {
        this.team2 = team2;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getToss_winner_team() {
        return toss_winner_team;
    }

    public void setToss_winner_team(String toss_winner_team) {
        this.toss_winner_team = toss_winner_team;
    }

    public boolean isSquad() {
        return squad;
    }

    public void setSquad(boolean squad) {
        this.squad = squad;
    }

    public boolean isMatchStarted() {
        return matchStarted;
    }

    public void setMatchStarted(boolean matchStarted) {
        this.matchStarted = matchStarted;
    }
}
```

**My Provider class**

```
package com.piyushjaiswal.jsonpractis;

public class provider {
    private String source;
    private String url;
    private String pubDate;

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getPubDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }

    public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity Class**

```
package com.piyushjaiswal.jsonpractis;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textView;
private JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://cricapi.com/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);
        getMatchList();
    }

    private void getMatchList() {

        Call<List<MatchesArray>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPosts("JimJAfsmRGOnDpCrRrqO6htlilg1");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MatchesArray>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<MatchesArray>> call, Response<List<MatchesArray>> response) {
                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    textView.setText(response.message() + "123");
                    return;
                }
               List<MatchesArray> list = response.body();
                textView.setText(list.get(0).getMatches().getDate());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<MatchesArray>> call, Throwable t) {
                textView.setText(t.getMessage() +"22");

            }
        });


    }

}
```

But output on screenshot is
**"Expected BEGIB_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 patg $2"**

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON syntax is wrong. The response starts with `{"matches":[`, this means it is an object, with the parameter `matches` that is of type `match[]`.

So, you need a new class along the lines of:

```
public class MatchesWrapper {
    private List<Matches> matches;
}
```

And change all your `Call<List<MatchesArray>>` to `Call<MatchesWrapper>`.

---

The error you received tells you this. You expected an array of `Matches` (`Expected BEGIN_ARRAY`), but instead received an object (`was BEGIN_OBJECT`).